# Trouble with std::ostringstream as function parameter

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stringstream

So I got stuck on a simple print-function today and I really don't know how to fix this problem. Basically I want to pass my Strings to a function in a std::cout-style like this:

```
foo(std::ostringstream() << "Hello" << " World!");
```

And from what I've read it should be possible by a function along the lines of

```
void foo(std::ostringstream& in)
```

but when implementing I get a somewhat strange behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void foo(std::ostringstream& in)
{
    std::cout << in.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream working;
    working << "Hello" << " World!";
    foo(working);                   // OK
    std::ostringstream notWorking;
    notWorking << "Hello";
    foo(notWorking<<" World!");     // Not OK?!
    return 0;
}
```

While the first call of foo seems fine and works like expected, the second one refuses to compile even though they should (from my perspective) be technically the same thing.

Error:

```
error C2664: 'void foo(std::ostringstream &)': cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' to 'std::ostringstream &'
```

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2013 Express on Win7 x64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overloads of shifting operators for IO operations take the base streams by reference. That is:

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os , foo myfo )
{
    os << myfoo;

    return os;
}
```

So use `std::ostream` instead of `std::ostringstream` as function parameter:

```
void f( std::ostream& stream );
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be working. How do I get back from an std::ostream to std::string though? Shifting it into std::cout doesn't seem to work for example.

Comment: @CyDek If `foo` really needs an `ostringstream` you should use your *working* method instead of modifying the function to take an `ostream`. If you really want to follow your other method, then you could cast the `ostream` back to `ostringstream` (`static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(in).str()`) but then it'd be undefined behavior if someone calls `foo` with some other kind of `ostream`

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks, works like a charm. Since I'm really just experimenting for learning purposes I am actually quite fine with that :)

Answer (score 2):

It's simply because the second expression

```
notWorking<<" World!"
```

returns a `std::ostream&` not a `std::ostringsream&`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is that you’re trying to implicitly downcast an `ostream` into an `ostringstream` because the result of the `<<` operator is always `ostream&` regardless of the concrete string type. Changing `foo()` to take an `ostream&` ought to solve this, unless you need to rely specifically on `ostringstream` features in the implementation of `foo`, in which case you can `dynamic_cast`.

Also, by constructing a temporary `ostringstream` in your `foo(std::ostringstream() << "Hello" << " World!");` example, you obtain an rvalue. `foo()` expects an lvalue reference to the stream. You might be able to get away with changing `foo()` to take an rvalue reference: `std::ostream&&`.

Comment: What temporary `ostringstream`?

Comment: @Praetorian: `foo(std::ostringstream() << "Hello" << " World!");` though the `ostream`/`ostringstream` distinction is also relevant.

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that first line. Anyway, his code sample doesn't have any such thing.